# How to create group chat with xmpp framework in Iphone?

Tags: iphone, xmpp

I have use `xmpp framework` in my application and send the chat message with individual user.

But now i want to chat with multiple user so how can i do this?

Comment: Is this question about XMPP? Or about certain library? And how it is related to iPhone in particular?

Comment: Check if this is useful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17025843/how-to-implement-group-chat-with-xmpp-framework-in-ios

Comment: possible duplicate of [XMPPFramework - How to create a MUC room and invite users?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786813/xmppframework-how-to-create-a-muc-room-and-invite-users)