# XMPPFramework - Group Chat Implementation

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

I need to implement group chat using XMPP. I Implemented one-to-one chat with Openfire server. Any body knows please post the code.

Comment: I need to implement u have code pls help me @spider

Comment: Take a read at this similar thread: [XMPPFramework - How to create a MUC room and invite users?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786813/how-to-create-a-room-and-invite-users-using-xmppframework)

Answer (score 2):

Link :

> https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki/GettingStarted_iOS

the above git repo comes with a sample project try following it, copy pasting isn't a solution i guess.

also you can go through :

> http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-xmpp-integration/

for a tutorial,with all the basic implementation done.

Comment: I know how to implement one to one chatting> i Want to know group chat.If u know pls post the code

Comment: for group chat refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268629/xmpp-ios-chat-client-implement-group-chat

Comment: I referred that link In that how to send message to multible clients .please tell me

Comment: in this you will send your message to chat room rather than clients they all will be getting the message if they have joined the chat room you are sending your message.

Comment: Spider Please send me code how to create room. I am very needed .If u have Please .

Comment: follow this this is with code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268629/xmpp-ios-chat-client-implement-group-chat